# Why can't I access new folders on my site? .htaccess issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

when I try to create a new folder on my site, I can not access it. This is a htaccess issue because when I delete the following code, access to the folder is available.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\/$ /game.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\/$ /category.php?cid=$1&page=$2&title=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

How can I access my new folder without messing with the functionality of the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell it to ignore `real` files or folders.

```
RewriteEngine On

#if it's a real file or dir don't rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\/$ /game.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\/$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\/$ /category.php?cid=$1&page=$2&title=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

Comment: Perfect. Works great! Thank you.